# Can't bind $scope in controller when scope: {} is defined in the directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I bind a `$scope` within the controller of a directive without using `scope: {}` in the directive settings it works.

But I need `scope: {}` to get a defined variable inside the directive.

This is my test code:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive("directive", function () {
  return {
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.id = 5;
    }
  }
});

app.directive("childDirective", function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      id: "=user"
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.hello = "Hello";
    }
  }
})
```

-

```
<html ng-app="app">

<directive>
  <child-directive user="id">
     {{ hello }}
  </child-directive>
</directive>

</html>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyEXJV

when I remove `scope: { id: "=user" }` it works. But I need to pass the id to the controller.

Is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use an isolated scope it is only valid on the template provided for the directive. You can provide the template as a string or as `templateUrl`

Try this way:

```
<directive>
  <child-directive user="id"></child-directive>
</directive>
```

JS

```
app.directive("childDirective", function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      id: "=user"
    },        
    template:'{{ hello }} ID= {{id}}',
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.hello = "Hello";
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Should I use a controller instead if I want the template to be custom made?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. Read up on `isolated scope` in directives

Comment: All right! Your solution is working so I will mark the answer as accepted. Im going to read up on isolated scopes in directives. thanks